# SOAP Convert xml to wsdl

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I have been given this xml file instead of a xsdl file for SOAP usage, is there a way I can convert this file to xsdl for use with PHP's SoapClient() ?

MasterData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp200409="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsp200607="http://www.w3.org/2006/07/ws-policy" xmlns:ns0="http://www.post.ch/npp/trackandtracews/v02/masterdata/definitions" targetNamespace="http://www.post.ch/npp/trackandtracews/v02/masterdata/definitions">
<wsdl:types xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="MasterData.ws.xsd1.xsd" namespace="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></xsd:schema></wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="DetailRequest">
<wsdl:part name="DetailRequest" element="xsns:DetailReq" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="DetailResponse">
<wsdl:part name="DetailResponse" element="xsns:DetailRes" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="EventsRequest">
<wsdl:part name="EventsRequest" element="xsns:EventsReq" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="EventsResponse">
<wsdl:part name="EventsResponse" element="xsns:EventsRes" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="StatusesRequest">
<wsdl:part name="StatusesRequest" element="xsns:StatusReq" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="StatusesResponse">
<wsdl:part name="StatusesResponse" element="xsns:StatusRes" xmlns:xsns="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdata/v02"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="MasterDataResource">
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllDetails">
<wsdl:input name="DetailRequest" message="ns0:DetailRequest"/>
<wsdl:output name="DetailResponse" message="ns0:DetailResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllEvents">
<wsdl:input name="EventsRequest" message="ns0:EventsRequest"/>
<wsdl:output name="EventsResponse" message="ns0:EventsResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllStatuses">
<wsdl:input name="StatusesRequest" message="ns0:StatusesRequest"/>
<wsdl:output name="StatusesResponse" message="ns0:StatusesResponse"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="MasterDataBinding" type="ns0:MasterDataResource">
<soap11:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllDetails">
<soap11:operation soapAction="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdataws/v02/GetAllDetails" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="DetailRequest">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="DetailResponse">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllEvents">
<soap11:operation soapAction="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdataws/v02/GetAllEvents" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="EventsRequest">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="EventsResponse">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAllStatuses">
<soap11:operation soapAction="http://www.post.ch/npp/masterdataws/v02/GetAllStatuses" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="StatusesRequest">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="StatusesResponse">
<soap11:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="MasterDataService">
<wsdl:port name="MasterDataPort" binding="ns0:MasterDataBinding">
<soap11:address location="https://webservices.post.ch:443/IN_MYPBxTT/services/MasterData.ws"/></wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="MasterDataPort.0" binding="ns0:MasterDataBinding">
<soap11:address location="https://webservices.post.ch:443/IN_MYPBxTT/services/MasterData.ws"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Any help would be much appreaciated because I have been stuck on this since this morning...

I want to call this file like this

```
$SOAP_Client = new SoapClient('MasterData.wsdl')
```

Comment: save as 'MasterData.wsdl'

Comment: You have everything you need.